My Kotlin application crashes when changing fragments
My Kotlin application crashes when I change fragments, let me explain.
My application has several fragments which are my pages, in my fragments I refer to the XML view by a viewBinding like this:
private var binding: MyFragmentBinding by autoCleared()

I made several API calls and other processing in the onViewCreated (which works perfectly) until everything is fine but now if I press the back button on the phone before the elements have finished loading, the application crashes with the mistake :
FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
Process: fr.trecobat.brick, PID: 6594
java.lang.IllegalStateException: should never call auto-cleared-value get when it might not be available
at fr.trecobat.brick.utils.AutoClearedValue.getValue(AutoClearedValue.kt:32)
fr.trecobat.brick.ui.itineraire_chantiers.ItineraireChantiersFragment.getBinding(ItineraireChantiersFragment.kt:198)

The problem is that I'm trying to access the binding when the fragment is destroyed.
In the same way, if I spam the phone's back button, I think that the previous fragment does not have time to load and I return to the previous fragment, so the application crashes with this error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
Process: fr.trecobat.brick, PID: 26518
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination fr.trecobat.brick:id/action_tourneeFragment_to_selectionChantierFragment cannot be found from the current destination Destination(fr.trecobat.brick:id/selectionChantierFragment) label=SelectionChantierFragment class=fr.trecobat.brick.ui.selection_chantier.SelectionChantierFragment
at fr.trecobat.brick.ui.tournee.TourneeFragment$onViewCreated$3.handleOnBackPressed(TourneeFragment.kt:176)

For now I have tried these two solutions.
I replaced the line that auto cleans the binding with this:
private var binding: MyFragmentBinding by notNull()

It seems to work but I lose self-cleaning and potentially expose myself to memory leaks, right?
For the second option in my onBackPressedDispatcher I set a timer:
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
    viewLifecycleOwner,
    object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            if (canNavigate) {
                canNavigate = false
                handler.postDelayed({ canNavigate = true }, 300)  // 300ms

                findNavController().navigate(
                    R.id.action_itineraireChantiersFragment_to_tourneeAffairesFragment,
                    bundleOf(
                        "touId" to touId,
                    )
                )
            }else{
                Timber.e("Stop back")
            }
        }
    }
)

This avoids aggressive page switching but is it the right solution?
Do you have any better solutions for my problems?


The problem is that I'm trying to access the binding when the fragment is destroyed.

Yes, API calls may take some time, and they may still be active even if your fragment is destroyed. When they are finished and try to access binding, it might be null because your fragment could already be destroyed.

It seems to work but I lose self-cleaning and potentially expose myself to memory leaks, right?

Yes, because of the way the Fragments were designed, they can outlive their views and can be reused with a different view. So we need to nullify the binding when the fragment is destroyed.
Recommended solution

Use ViewModel

private class YourViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val _apiResult = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)
    val apiResult get() = _apiResult.asStateFlow()

    fun loadDataFromApi() {
        val hello = "world" // load data from api
        _apiResult.update { hello }
    }
}

And in your fragment
private val viewModel by viewModels<YourViewModel>()

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            launch {
                viewModel.apiResult.collect { apiResult ->
                    // set data to your views here
                }
            }
        }
    }

    viewModel.loadDataFromApi()
}


Hacky trick

You can check if the fragment is alive and safe to use binding before accessing binding.
fun Fragment.isSafe(): Boolean {
        return !(this.isRemoving || this.activity == null || this.isDetached || !this.isAdded || this.view == null)
}

For the second problem, it seems more context is needed to identify the issue. Maybe this answer will help.

In this documentation, android officials teach you how to figure out memory leak by yourself so that they don't have to answer on each and every test cases a user may perform. Besides you can use LeakCanary which does a great job in detecting memory leak.
Imagine if you have a Fragment and it has references to some properties. We need to clear the references to these fields by assigning null in onDestroyView() lifecycle method so that Fragment won’t hold references to them.
So in your case, No need to use by autoCleared() neither by notNull(), you can try something as simple as this:
    private var _binding: ProfileBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val mAdapter = MyListAdapter()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
       _binding = ProfileBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
       val view = binding.root
       binding.recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
       return view
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
       super.onDestroyView()
       binding.recyclerView.adapter = null
       _binding = null
    }


There's no reason to clear the adapter like that.  Remember that the entire view structure (including the RecyclerView) is being thrown away.

Yes exaclty, you're right, but the main idea is that Fragments outlive their views. so make sure you clean up any references to the binding class instance in the fragment’s onDestroyView() method.
